# How to copy list of files using puppet

Tags: puppet

In puppet is it possible to copy of list of files

Tried below code, but didn't work

```
$list_files = ['file1','file2','file2']

file { $list_files:
   ensure => present,
   path   => /tmp,
   source => 'puppet:///modules/$module_name/list_file_dir/$list_files',
}
```

any Suggestions?

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#each

Comment: @MattSchuchard,
data.each |$item| {
file { /tmp/$item:
   ensure. => present,
   source  => 'puppet:///modules/test_module/$item'
}

Comment: Your array is named `list_files`, and you need `"` to interpolate a string and not `'`, but otherwise yes: that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you can use the each switch e.g.

```
['file1','file2','file2'].each |$flie| {
  file{ "/tmp/${file}":
    ensure => file,
    source => "puppet:///modules/$module_name/list_file_dir/${file}",
  }
}
```

however it is also worth noting that you can pass a directory to both the destination and the source parameter e.g. if you have the directory `puppet:///modules/$module_name/list_file_dir` on your puppet master with the files `['file1','file2','file2']` then you can copy them all to temp using the following

```
file { '/tmp':
  ensure => directory,
  source => 'puppet:///modules/$module_name/list_file_dir',
  recurse => remote,
}
```

using `recurse => remote` remote ensures puppet only manages files which exist in the remote location (i.e. the puppetmaster)

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/file.html#file-attribute-recurse